# Integrating lucene or solr with java derby DB

Tags: java, swing, solr, lucene, derby

am developing a desktop application with a textfield 
that users will enter text characters the database will then be searched 
to find a marching string

for example

if a user enters the phrase "bigger than life"

the system should search all the columns in the database 
 for a marching string.I am using the java derby database with NetBeans IDE.

Is it possible to use the lucene or solr 
search engines to serch through the java derby DB

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DataImportHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to pull data from Derby into Solr schema. Then, you use [eDisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) as a search algorithm to look for stuff over all your fields.

Comment: but are there tutorials to give examples of their implementation will be greatfull to have some

Comment: What are you having difficulty with? Derby has a standard JDBC driver. DataImportHandler has an example of using JDBC connection and mapping the fields. eDisMax page has example of how to search across multiple fields. Solr distribution has a number of examples showing how to define fields, use DIH and even has a full tutorial on starting with Solr. If you are running in a specific issue while following these, ask a separate detailed question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is possible to integrate them. Here is a brief tutorial by Apache it self.

[LuceneDerbyIntegration](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/LuceneIntegration)

Answer (score 0):

According to DERBY-590, a patch is available, not fully baked yet:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-590